# Zoom in on a Youtube video on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video

How can I programmatically control the zoom and offset to focus on only a certain part of the screen while playing a Youtube video (launched through a webview) on iPhone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not at all - you can not do that.